# Error retrieving data in ajax when returning a list of objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I used the following ajax code to invoke a method and retrieve a list of objects.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(selectedCompany),
            url: "/InspectionData/RetrieveInspectionData",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("HERE");
```

The method in the code behind is:

```
public JsonResult RetrieveInspectionData(string companyID)
        {
            var iData = db.InspectionDatas.Where(d => d.companyId == companyID).ToList();
            return Json(iData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that when there is some data present in `iData` the alert is not invoked and there is some Internal Server Error (500) in the javascript. On the other hand if `iData` is empty or if I replace it with any other regular list, it enters the function and the alert is printed. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Internal Server Error (500) in the javascript` is incorrect in your case, It is internal server error which means it was thrown during some operation in your action/server. Look at the network console that will give you clues on what cause `500` server error.

Comment: BTW what is the type that you get as a result of `db.InspectionDatas` query?

Comment: `db.InspectionDatas` is an object set of `InspectionData` which is a table in the database.

Comment: look at the network tab for your ajax request and what does the error response say?

Answer (score 0):

Is the iData underlying data type properly serialized with DataContract attribute?

Comment: I am not sure. Since I am new to the language, I do not quite understand what you mean or how I can check for the same. Please help!

Comment: Cab you debug the application and see what errors you get then post it here? Thanks

Comment: That's extremely strange since you are getting a 500 error. Anyway, can you decorate the Action method with the HttpPost attribute and remove the jsonbehabiour since you don't need it?

Comment: It still doesn't work. There are no runtime errors. I only get the 500 error in the javascript as before.